Determining how much timeseries relationships are driven by periodicity versus date relationships?
Given three timeseries of monthly data all ending at 11/30/2024 (A beginning at 12/31/2023, B beginning at 3/31/2024, and C beginning at 9/30/2024), one could present the timeseries as 1) aligned on the basis of period (lining up A's period 0 12/31/2023 with B's period 0 3/31/2024) or 2) aligned on the basis of date (lining up A's period 3 3/31/2024 with B's period 0 3/31/2024). Is there an accepted statistical technique(s) to measure the 'driver' of correlation of the timeseries based on periodicity versus date?
